# Prove $\frac1{x^4} < \frac1{x^3} - \frac1{(x+1)^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that for $x \ge 2$, $$\frac1{x^4} < \frac1{x^3} - \frac1{(x+1)^3}.$$

What I have so far is:
$${1\over x^3} - {1\over (x+1)^3} = {(x+1)^3-x^3\over x^3(x+1)^3} = {3x^2+3x+1\over x^3(x+1)^3} > {(x+1)^2\over x^3(x+1)^3} = {1\over x^3(x+1)}.$$
As seen, this won't lead to the correct expression, so could anyone give me any hints on how should I approach the question algebraically?

I've thought of using the graph of ${1\over x^4}$ and using the area-under the graph but I was thinking if there is a trick to solving it via algebraic means.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{3x^2+3x+1}{x^3(x+1)^3}$$

$$\gt\frac{3x^2+3x}{x^3(x+1)^3}$$

$$=\frac{3}{x^2(x+1)^2}$$

$$\gt\frac{1}{x^4}$$

because for $x\ge2$

$$\frac{3}{(x+1)^2}\ge \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align*}{1\over x^3} - {1\over (x+1)^3}-\frac{1}{x^4}=\frac{2x^3-2x-1}{x^4(x+1)^3}>0 \qquad(x\geq 2)
\end{align*}